# Please help me to configure my server to give high performance for wordpress

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, wordpress, php5

I am using 2GB ram,2 core XEON processor. I want to configure my Apache, MySQL and PHP for giving me high performance, as of now when i try to test my server with stress test , it is breaking down fast.

when i see logs, it says out of memory for apache and mysql.

please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

The classic situation that is almost certainly happening to you is that all your physical memory (RAM) is being consumed by your running Applications, causing swap to be used. As your machine starts using your swap space, you'll find that IO starts slowing down (because using your swap is using your available IO also), which causes page loads to take longer. This in turn causes more page renders to linger for longer, and as you're constantly feeding in more requests for pages, the cycle feeds itself and your machine ends up becoming unresponsive under the weight of swap io.

The key here is that you need to set boundaries with respect to memory for MySQL and Apache (php is generally lumped in with Apache here).

Firstly, you need to have an idea of how much memory you're going to need to run MySQL, and then set limits to MySQL. There is information on this process all over the internet, and on this site.

In the memory you have left over after you allocate some for the system, and then some for MySQL, you need to look at apache/php.

The number of apache children you can have serving at once very much depends on how much memory Wordpress is using for a single page load which can vary GREATLY depending on what plugins you have active at any time in wordpress. The ideal first step is to assess the maximum memory a php process can use, since you're probably not using more than that plus a little overhead for apache per page load.

Then, divide that into your available RAM and you'll be in the vicinity of a reasonable place to start for a number for MaxClients for Apache. Again, there is information on limiting apache memory usage in many places, someone may link some in this thread.

The main thing to remember is my first advice; you're more than likely using more memory than you have available physical RAM, which is causing heavy swap usage. In the case of ongoing heavy load on your server, it's a situation that cannot be resolved without limitations.

Before you wonder if you need to even worry about this "worst case" scenario, I have to say that you almost certainly do; there's nothing that's as much fun as having to hard reset linux machines because the aforementioned calculations haven't been done and yet another machine has become unresponsive in the middle of the night as a spider or other annoying robot crawls your site.